# NAUTY algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, math-software, graph-isomorphism

NAUTY is a Graph Isomorphism(GI) software developed by  Brendan McKay to test isomorphism of Graphs. It  provides a practical solution to the Graph Isomorphism problem. It is a program for isomorphism and automorphism of graphs.

At the moment I am studying  GI, and my query is-
How does NAUTY  works?

As much I understood, NAUTY  uses *Vertex Classification*, but what happens when a *Regular Graph*(when *Vertex Classification* is meaningless) is given to NAUTY ?

It would be helpful to have an overview of  NAUTY algorithm. To be precise, how it's *Search Tree* works?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  edited, enough?

Comment: I'll put this link here just in case you haven't checked out the user guide: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/nug25.pdf  (Maybe the references in there might help?)

Comment: @A.Sh , yes I have, see section 10 if you have not yet.

Comment: I'll admit that I haven't looked too much into this before, so I'm pretty much in your position. I skimmed through this reference: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/pgi.pdf (its number 9 in the reference list in the user guide), and I will have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4881 (reference number 10). Both of these papers seem to explain the methods behind the software, so I suggest reading through those.

Comment: @A.Sh Practical Graph Isomorphism 1, 2 both  describe the theory behind NAUTY , but  it takes a lot of  knowledge  to read those papers, as a starter it is extremely difficult for me to  decrypt those paper ( I have started   reading Practical Graph Isomorphism 1) , so a liitle help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I can't make promises, but it does lie in my interests to understand this as well. I'll read as much as my schedule permits, and hope someone else can take over, should I fail to be of assistance.

Comment: @A.Sh  thanks , I appreciate your help, I am also studying. Please, get back if you have something.

Comment: While software to solve graph isomorphism problems is no doubt interesting to many, I'm concerned that the framing of this question is overly broad and tending to the details of the software implementation (NAUTY) rather than to a topic about algorithms.  Note that there have been recent announcements of advances in the area of graph isomorphism, and I'd rather see that sort of content than a package-specific approach.

Comment: It would be possible to make this question less specific - oddly enough, it is currently 'too broad' - by generalizing to all partition refinement approaches to GI. There are a bunch of nAUTy-like programs (saucy, traces, bliss) that use the same approach. Alternatively, this page : http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Introduction.html gives a nice overview, although not very mathematical.

Comment: @gilleain thanks for your comment(you could have used that page to write an answer if you understand  Practical Graph isomorphism 1,2 By Mckay ). Note that I am not looking for mathematical description. Practical Graph isomorphism By Mckay is full of technical details  which is really hard to get for a novice like me. So, an "Overview" would be nice an I don't consider that "too broad".

Comment: ok, so there's one explanation here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/27001051/415384 that might help

Comment: @gilleain , that will do some help! thanks mate.